# Importing more than one Java object into a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, constructor

Our CS class was assigned to make a program that imports two java objects into a class which is supposed to return a face value of a set of dice. The Die class generates a random number and prints the value onto the screen. The testDie class imports two die object arrays with one having six sides the other having 15. The program only prints out the value of the dice with six sides (it's an array of dice btw) and doesn't print out the other 15 sided die. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

The following is my Die class, which generates a random face value

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

            int face;  //current value of the face of the die object
            int numSides; //number of sides of the die object
            Random ran = new Random();
            Random ran2 = new Random();


    public Die(){//default constructor

        int numSides = 0;
        int face = 0;

    }
    public Die (int sides){

        sides = numSides;
        face = 0;
        setSides();
    }

    private void setSides() {
        if(numSides > 6)
            face = roll2();
        if(numSides <= 6)
            face = roll();
    }



    public int getFace(){
        return face;

    }

    public int getNumSides(){

        return numSides;
    }

    public int roll(){

        return face = ran.nextInt(6) +1; //generates a random number between 1 and 6.
    }

    public int roll2(){
        return face = ran2.nextInt(20) + 7; // generates a random number between 7 and 20.
    }

    public String toString(){

        return Integer.toString(face);  
    }


}
```

This code is creating two die objects and prints it out to the screen.

```
public class TestDie extends Die {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


          Die[] dieobject = new Die[3];

        for (int i=0; i< dieobject.length; i++)
        {
            dieobject[i] = new Die(6); // a die with 6 sides
        }

        for (int i=0; i<dieobject.length; i++) // prints out the 3 dice face values
        {
            System.out.println("The value of die " + (i+1)  + " is " + dieobject[i].toString());
        }


          Die[] dieobject2 = new Die[3];

        for (int i=0; i< dieobject2.length; i++)
        {
            dieobject2[i] = new Die(15); // a die with 15 sides
        }

        for (int i=0; i<dieobject2.length; i++) // prints out the 3 dice face values
        {
            System.out.println("The value of die " + (i+1)  + " is " + dieobject2[i].toString());
        }


    }
}
```

Sorry for the poor formatting. I'm new to this site. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than apologize for poor formatting, have a look at the [formatting help site](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: You're also using the term "import" incorrectly. In Java, it specifically refers to finding a class in another package and mapping it to the current file so that you can use its short name, so that you can say `import java.util.Map` and then just use `Map` thereafter.

Comment: Why does TestDie extend Die?

Comment: `return face = ran2.nextInt(20) + 7; // generates a random number between 7 and 20` <- wrong, generates number between 7 and 26

Answer (score 1):

Your roll method looks broken. Why have more than one roll method anyway? Just have one that returns a random number up to but not including the number of sides.

---

Also this is wrong:

```
public Die (int sides){

    sides = numSides;  // this is backwards
    face = 0;
    setSides();
}
```

You have reversed the sides vs numSides as you are setting your parameter not your field.

so instead it's

```
this.numSides = sides;
```

The main problem with your code is that you're not doing some debugging as you're creating it. You need to test each method in isolation to be sure that it works.

---

And as mentioned, there's no reason for TestDie to extend the Die class and lots of reasons not to do this.